# Tool to reformat xml-comments (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros, xml-comments, add-on

does anyone know of a macro or add-on for VS 2008 which reformats xml-comments? There has been this really smart CommentReflower for the older version of VS, but I couldn't find a release supporting VS 2008.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=389&Itemid=57) tools in the past to help keep XML comments inline.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at AutoHotKey to create a small script which can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

[HyperAddin](http://www.codeplex.com/hyperAddin) has a FormatComment option, which may or may not do what you want.

(I use it mostly to be able to hyper-link to other bits of code.)